# c# Uri is well formatted

Tags: c#, uri

I understand Uri.IsWellFormedUriString() returns true if it is a "well formatted URI." My question is how does this check the validity of the URI? Another developer was telling me that it checks whether or not the URI exists. When I read the documentation it seems like it does as the name suggest. That is... it just checks it is formatted correctly. When this method is called I see no packets being sent over the network.

If I am correct, is there a function that would work to make sure the URI exists/is valid? And what if authentication required? Will it check if the correct authentications is provided?

I am running into issues on streaming and am trying to trouble shoot my issue.

Comment: "*Another developer was telling me that it checks whether or not the URI exists*" - they are completely wrong. The documentation tells you what it checks for

Comment: "*If I am correct, is there a function that would work to make sure the URI exists/is valid*
 - i am not sure what you actually mean by this. The only way to check if a remote resource exists is to call it

Comment: I have written a program that through a series of soaps over HTTP gets information concerning some custom-built devices at a specific IP Address. The information I get back tells me how to construct the URI to access specific features for a given device. I am still unable to access the needed features. This leads me to believe I am either 
a) building the URI incorrectly based off the information I received or
b) I have built the URI correctly but am writing my request for access to a specific feature incorrectly.

Comment: You are right its likely A or B. The `IsWellFormedUriString` is only a sanity check, i don't think there is much we can help with, you are likely best contacting the manufacturer, or just keep trying things until you get something that works

Comment: Yea! I tried that! Its been two weeks and I still haven't heard back. Thanks either way.

Comment: i think it use **Regex**

Comment: Are you looking for [ping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=netcore-3.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the url is valid or currently active you can do something like this.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(url);
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);

try
{
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    // URL IS VALID/ACTIVE DO YOUR LOGIC HERE
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // URL IS NOT VALID/ACTIVE DO YOUR LOGIC HERE
}
```

Comment: The docu of WebRequest states not to use it anymore and instead use HttpClient. WebRequest has been deprecated nearly a decade ago.